# How to excluding directories in InteliJ IDEA (advanced)?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know about «Project Structure | Module» but as it is it does not help so I am looking for some advanced informations.

Let me explain:

I have a lot of hidden «.backup» directories and adding them all in «Project Structure | Module» the is quite painful. An exclude pattern matcher would be nice. Perhaps a plug-in.

While painful it is not impossible to add all «.backup» directories to «Project Structure | Module». If only the setting would stick. But they don't. I more or less have to fill them in once a day.

This could be because I develop alternating on Mac OS X and Windows. On maybe because I use Maven. Any issues or best practises I should be aware off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Settings | File Types | Ignore files and folders**.

Comment: [my first down-vote] Read my first sentence: **I know that already**. I am looking for a **better** solution. Or perhaps I am using it the wrong way. The I would need some more **in deeps** informations.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention what I've suggested anywhere. Double check my reply or see this screenshot if you don't understand what I am suggesting and don't see any difference between Module settings and File Types: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/snap0239.png. And feel free to down-vote yourself for ignorance =)

Comment: @Martin you should be more attentive. This answer contains exactly what you need.

Comment: I hate to be wrong but but here I am. You are right, I am wrong.